# I can't connect to sqlite db using ASP.NET Core configbuilder

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to connect to my sqlite database, I've got the connection string setup in the `appsettigns.json` file, however for some reason when I'm trying to add `addDbContext` as a service, it's not doing anything and it runs with no error and no logs. As if it was not even  getting the context properly.

Here's the `appdbcontext.cs` class

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

Here's the `Program.cs` :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Portfolio_Blog.Data;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Create a logger
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("MyApplication");
// Configure services
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
// Log a message
logger.LogInformation("Connection string setup point reached");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    options.UseSqlite(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

    if (options.IsConfigured)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Connected to the database.");
    }
    else
    {
        logger.LogError("Failed to connect to the database.");
    }
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

// Configure the database context using the connection string

app.Run();
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone help me?

Update :

I'm using Dotnet 7, I've verified that my sqlite file didn't have no weird access restrictions, checked the connection string as well.

I feel like there is a tiny thing that I'm missing ...

UPDATE : I've found the issue, it was the type of project that i had used that wasn't the proper one to run this, i've switched to a aspnet web api project and everything worked fine :)

Comment: _"no error and no logs"_ -  so your app is running just fine then?

Comment: Please provide info -  environment you are running the code, your app config, and expected behavior which is not mached.

Comment: P.S. `options.IsConfigured` is  relatively useless.

Comment: I should be getting the log information, ''connected'' or ''failed'' when I'm running the app. But I'm not. I'm running the app on vscommunity it's .net 7 code.